# Using getByte() with primitive data

Tags: java, methods, boolean, int, primitive-types

In JAVA the method ***getByte()*** is undefined for for Ints, Booleans and all primitive data types (I believe).

- Is there a way I can get my Boolean and/or Int variables to work with
  the method.
- Or what data type do you recommend i change the variables too.

Comment: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=6529 check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to convert primitives to `byte[]` and vice versa

Example

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(int value) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    return bb.putInt(value).array();
}

public static int toInteger(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    return bb.getInt();
}
```

Comment: +1 You might want to use `ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteBuffer.nativeOrder());` and `ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteBuffer.nativeOrder());`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks Learnt a better way :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you only need the individual bytes if you are writing to a binary stream.  If this is what it is for, I suggest you use `DataOutputStream` to write network/big-endian to an OutputStream or `ByteBuffer` if you need little-endian or you are writing to NIO or NIO2.

If you need to perform bit-wise operations such as get the lower 8 bits, you can use a mask with `&` or some combination with `>>>` to get other bits.  Which operations to use depends on what you need this for.